# How to use Task.Factory.StartNew<TResult> when TResult is a Task<object>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Running into a bit of a roadblock using the Task Parallel Library to call a method that returns a Task.

I have a class called MspClient which contains an async method called MakeMspCallAsync

```
public class MspClient
{        
    public async Task<IMspCallResponse> MakeMspCallAsync(IMspCallRequest request)
    {
        var response = new MspCallResponse();
        ... 
        await ...
        ...
        return response;
    }
}
```

In my program that uses the MspClient class, I want to write something along these lines:

```
using (var mspClient = new MspClient())
{
    Task<IMspCallResponse>[] tasks = new Task<IMspCallResponse>[ctx.Message.MspCallRequests.Count];

    for(int i = 0; i < ctx.Message.MspCallRequests.Count; i++)
    {
        var mspCallRequest = ctx.Message.MspCallRequests[i];        
        tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew<IMspCallResponse>(mspClient.MakeMspCallAsync(mspCallRequest));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

The compile time exception occurs on this line:

```
tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew<IMspCallResponse>(mspClient.MakeMspCallAsync(mspCallRequest));

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew<IMspCallResponse>(System.Func<IMspCallResponse>)' has some invalid arguments  

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<IMspCallResponse>' to 'System.Func<IMspCallResponse>'
```

Pretty sure I'm overlooking something very simple but can't wrap my head around it, can someone please help me out?  Thanks.

Comment: You already got the answer (use `Task.Run` instead of `StartNew`, and use a delegate), but I must point out that running asynchronous methods on multiple threads and then (synchronously) blocking, waiting for them to complete, is almost certainly wrong. Your program would probably work better with `await Task.WhenAll` instead of `Task.WaitAll`, and removing the `Task.Run` completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You at least need a delegate in there:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew<IMspCallResponse>(() => mspClient.MakeMspCallAsync(mspCallRequest));
```

However this will return a `Task<Task<IMspCallResponse>>`, which is a little unweildy. You will need to unwrap it (see `TaskExtensions.Unwrap`). `Task.Run` is better because it will do that for you:

```
tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => mspClient.MakeMspCallAsync(mspCallRequest));
```